# pushViewport to create subplot arrangment

Tags: r

I am trying to make subplots by using `pushViewport`
I need to create 2 subplots on first row and 1 subplot on second row

I use the following code

```
plot.new()
popViewport()
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1))
plot(0,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',pch='',ylab='',xlab='')
popViewport()
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 2))
plot(0,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',pch='',ylab='',xlab='')
popViewport(2)
popViewport()
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 2))
plot(0,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',pch='',ylab='',xlab='')
popViewport(3)
```

Two subplots on first row are working fine, but the one on second returns

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_unsetviewport, as.integer(n)) : 
  cannot pop the top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?)
```

Could you please tell whats wrong? Thank you!

Comment: it's pretty clear from the error message: grid and base graphics don't mix. `plot()` is (typically) a base graphics function, while viewports are for grid graphics. What are you trying to draw?

Comment: Actually, two plots on first row are forest plots, and on the bottom i need to print some text, but `mtext` and `text` functions do not work :( then i was thinking to create empty plot on bottom and add text to it

Comment: oh i found answer. thank you :)